# How Do I Get This Implementation of CoreData to Work in my Framework?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm trying to implement CoreData in a Framework. The framework is part of a couple of different apps, so the DB needs to be contained within the Framework (as opposed to having its own class somewhere in the app).

I'm following examples where the ViewController and AppDelegate manage the initialization of the app. Again, framework, so the structure is different. I have 6 classes in my Framework, but only two access the db, so I'm putting it in the one that does the heavy lifting, Game.

In the class definition for Game I have,

```
//    CoreData stuff
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext?
    
    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Word")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()
```

I need on a one-time basis to initialize the db with a list of words, so I have a function

```
    public func initCD() {
        do {
            context = persistentContainer.viewContext
            var words = try context?.fetch(Word.fetchRequest())
            print("starting count \(words?.count)")
            if words?.count == 0 {
                print(words?.count)
                getTextFile(words?.count)
                words = try context?.fetch(Word.fetchRequest())
                print(words?.count)
            } else {
                print("alneady saved \(words?.count) words")
            }
        } catch {
            print("not happening")
        }
    }
```

but this chokes when it gets to the reference to `Word` in both places with `Cannot find 'Word' in scope`. The function it calls, `getTextFile()` does the same thing, but I don't doubt solving this once will solve it everywhere....

Is there an obvious bad assumption here? The entity definition looks like this

[image: entity definition]

EDIT:

I found a good guide that made it easier to translate the previous versions based on AppDelegates and having the coredata functionality in the ViewController, to my Framework model. You can find it here: https://medium.com/@yoellev8/sharing-a-core-data-model-with-a-swift-framework-5d191ccec99e

I'll post my working code a little later when I've got it working more completely.

Comment: I advice agains naming the model the same as the entity but anyway from the screenshot it looks like the model is spelled with a lowercase w but you have used an uppercase w in your code, `let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Word")`, so you need to change this since the name argument is case sensitive

Comment: Hi Joakim – that does not appear to be the problem; I tried renaming the xcdata file to wordModel.xcdatamodeld, then leaving the Entity as Word, and changing the classname to Word, makes no difference. To me it looks like wherever the class is being generated, is out of scope somehow.

Comment: I think Cleaning and Building should work. Try `CMD+Shift+K`, then `CMD+B`.

Comment: And you did change the call to `let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "wordModel")`? Also when doing changes like this (renaming) in Core Data it is best to clean the build folder to make sure any old binaries are removed.

Comment: yes, but see edited addition above. Thanks for your help, Joakim and Niall

Answer (score 0):

I think a Project Clean and Build should work. Try `CMD+Shift+K`, then  `CMD+B`. I think the problem is that it can find the object in the files. This should allow you to reference the `Word` entity without issue.